# X2 IPA force carb pressure

Tags: kegging

What is a good pressure to force carb a double IPA in a five gallon keg? Is it possible to over carb when force carbing? This is the my first time trying this method and don't want to over do it if that's possible . Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the temperature of the beer and how carbonated you want it.  The style and the size of the keg are meaningless.

[Check out this carbonation chart to help with the PSI.](http://www.kegerators.com/carbonation-table.php)

I tend to set the PSI to what the table indicates and let it go for a week or two.
If you want to go faster, you can simply crank the pressure to 20-30PSI and shake it for 5 minutes, then taste it.  Do that as many times as it takes to get the right amount of carbonation for your tastes.  However, using the shake method can certainly result in over carbed beer. But you can bleed pressure and shake again to relieve it.

I don't like shaking all that much because it supposedly reduces foam stability in the beer.